# Show the JInternalFrame data in the middle of the form

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I am using JFrame which contains three sections. 1st section is Pane, which contains the 6 menu button (left side). 2nd section is also Pane, which displays the logo of the company on the top. The third section is DesktopPane in which I am using (calling) JInterenalFrame in the DesktopPane.
How to always show the JInterenalFrame content (form data) into the middle of DesktopPane?

[image: Facing issue to show JInternalFrame form data into middle.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Third section is DesktopPane in which I am using(calling) JInterenalFrame in the DesktopPane.

A JDesktopPane is used to display multiple JInternalFrames. A JInternalFrame can be dragged around the desktop pane.

From your picture it looks like you just have a single JPanel in that area. Therefore you should not be using JDesktopPanel and JInternalFrame.

Instead you just use a regular JPanel with a CardLayout. This you can replace each panel based on the selection from your menu on the left.

See [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information.

> Show the data into middle of the form

The easiest way to do this is to use a JPanel with a GridBagLayout.

So you need to wrap your current panel in a panel with the GridBagLayout.

So the basic code is:

```
JPanel welcomePanel. = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout() );

welcomePanel.add(currentPanel, new GridBagConstraints());
```

Now your "currentPanel" will be centered in the "welcomePanel", which has been added to your panel using the CardLayout.

Comment: I am a beginner. Hey! @camickr, I did not get it completely. I need some more help implement your suggestion. Answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61076558/insert-data-into-jtable-from-jtextfield-where-jtableheader-is-null?noredirect=1#comment108064383_61076558  if you know the answer.

Comment: @KumarAnilChaurasiya, *I did not get it completely.* - what did you not understand abut the solution to this stated problem? Did you ask a follow up question about the suggestions given? That question is completely different. It has nothing to do with "centering" components on a panel.